# How to delete the words with the pattern in text file

Tags: linux, bash, vi

I have the file delimit by comma (,)

```
word1,word2,word3,word4  
word80,word81,word82
```

This is what I want

```
word1,word2  
word80,word81
```

So, I need only two words per line and I don't care the rest including second comma (,)
word3 word4 word82 can be delete OR In easy way, deleting the line with condition; having comma more than one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:%s/^\([^,]+,[^,]+\),.*$/\1/
```

You don't need to do it in `vi`, though two other solutions are

```
awk -F, '{print $1 "," $2}'
```

and

```
cut -d, -f1-2
```

Comment: argh, what I get for testing with a different file.  Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Wow, there are so many ways... Here's something using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(^[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*\).*/\1/' $file_name
```

What about the first and last? With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 "," $NF}` $file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input | cut -d, -f1,2
word1,word2
word80,word81
```

You didn't specify language, since you flagged it as bash, i used it.